# Im creating a facial recognition program and I am getting a Thread BAD EXECUTION error and I don't know what to do

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit
import CoreImage

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var personPic: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        personPic.image = UIImage(named: "stupidsonny")

        detect()
    }

    func detect() {
        guard let personciImage = CIImage(image: personPic.image!) else {   //This line has the error
            return
        }
```

Comment: The `!` operator means "crash here" if `nil`.

Comment: "I don't know what to do" Learning Swift would be a good first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the `personPic` outlet isn't connected, or the "stupidsonny" image isn't getting found and loaded. It's hard to tell which since they're both being accessed on the same line.

To help narrow it down, you could put a `!` where you load the image:

```
personPic.image = UIImage(named: "stupidsonny")!
```

Comment: Thanks man. The image wasn't connecting because when I stated it as "stupidsonny" I forgot the JPG